# Find the mean of array1 scores when array2 has scored less than 10

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

```
>>> ravi = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)
>>> sai = np.random.randint(1,50,12).reshape(3,4)
>>> print(ravi)
>>> print(sai)

ravi= [[ 1  2  3  4]
       [ 5  6  7  8]
       [ 9 10 11 12]]

sai = [[40  3  7 31]
       [15 16 30 20]
       [28  1 27  5]]
```

for question 2 I tried the below code

```
scorer =  np.maximum(ravi,sai)
```

[image]

1. Consider the array values are the scores. Now I want to find the mean of 'ravi' score when 'sai' has scored less than 10.
2. Compare ravi and sai score in each match(here each element) and print the name of the player who has a high score in each match.
   Scorer gives each match max score in the array(scorer) instead I want their name should be printed.

It gives ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Please show the code which you have tried ?

Comment: I have mentioned the code which I've tried. I think the answer that should be i.e, mean of Ravi score 2+3+10+12 (as sai scored every time less than 10 i.e,  3,7,1,5).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean, the mean of all the scores corresponding to the ones where Sai scored less than 10, you can do that with `np.mean(ravi[sai < 10])`

Comment: yeah, It worked. I meant the mean of all the scores corresponding to the ones where Sai scored less than 10

Comment: Can you help me with the question 2 too

Comment: For question 2, if `ravi` and `sai` are the same length, then iterate through the length (`for i in range(len(ravi)`) and then if `ravi[i]` is greater than `sai[i]` then print Ravi, otherwise print Sai

Comment: It gives a ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Can you post the code that resulted in that `ValueError`

Comment: @saicharan this is because the arrays are two-dimensional, rather than one-dimensional. One solution could be to flatten `ravi` and `sai` into 1D arrays with [.flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for question 2 i.e, ravi and sai score in each match(here each element) and print the name of the player who has a high score in each match.

[image]